# How can I delay DialogFlow responses?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have created a chatbot in which I send several responses to a request, but the api sends the responses to my web page very fast, I need to know how I can delay this

Comment: Seems like a good idea to handle this within the code of your web page. Could you elaborate the languages/frameworks you are using so that we can assist you in finding a solution that suits your needs?

Comment: Good afternoon Teresa, I am new to chatbot programming and the chatbot that I developed in DialogFlow I implemented it on my personal page that was created only with HTML, CSS and a little JS

Comment: Do you communicate with the Dialogflow API using JS? You might want to wrap your responses in a `setTimeout()`. See for example [this explanation](https://www.sitepoint.com/delay-sleep-pause-wait/).

Comment: I have not really used a Webhook for my web page, I have only used for facebook, by chance do you have a library where I can put webhook for a web page?